# How to delete certain file type on multiple servers via powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to remove all .pfx files on multiple servers in my environment. I've tried using the following script but it doesn't seem to work and it doesn't spit out an error.

```
$Systems = Get-Content "$($env:USERPROFILE)\desktop\SystemList.txt"
foreach ($System in $Systems){
Remove-Item "\\$($System)\C$\*.pfx"}
```

I've tried changing the file type to a test file "nike.txt"

```
$Systems = Get-Content "$($env:USERPROFILE)\desktop\SystemList.txt"
foreach ($System in $Systems){
Remove-Item "\\$($System)\C$\nike.txt"}
```

It then gives me this error

```
   Remove-Item : Cannot find path '\\xxxxxx\C$\nike.txt' because it does not exist.
```

I'm thinking that I have to narrow down my directory to exactly where the file sits at for this script to work but is there a way to remove all PFX file type just by searching the whole C: via powershell?

Comment: `"\\$($System)\C$\*.pfx"` is read as `C:\*.pfx` (*on the remote system - given the UNC path*). So, if you're looking to only remove the files from the root of C:\, that's all you're doing. You  have to specify the `-Recurse` switch in order to search for the files in sub directories; may also need to use `-Force` to search for hidden files. End result being: `Remove-Item "\\$System\C$\" -Include "*.pfx" -Recurse -WhatIf`. As for your error on the 2nd example, I'd ensure the computer names are being passed properly.

Comment: "is there a way to remove all PFX file type just by searching the whole C: via powershell" yes, but it will take a long time. You might want to implement multi threading if there are multiple hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding the items from the root of the C: drive

```
$files = Get-ChildItem \\$System\C$ -Filter *.pfx

foreach($file in $files) {
   Remove-Item $file.FullName
}
```

It may not be the fastest way but it will work